# GoogleSignIn modify safe area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, google-signin

My view is in SwiftUI but my view model is in Swift (see [code](https://github.com/NelsonParrilla/GoogleSignin-bug)).

First, to reproduce the bug, I have to clear Safari History and Website Data in Settings -> Safari, in order that `GoogleSignIn` ask for login.

When I launch my app, my safe area bottom = 0. I open google authentication with these following lines:

```
let rootVC = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.windows.first?.rootViewController
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = rootVC
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
```

I log my account and when the google sheet disappear, the safe area bottom = 277.

Does anyone knows how to reset this safe area bottom to 0 ?

I'm using SwiftUI, XCode 12.5, Swift 5, Iphone SE 2 with iOS 14.4.1

Comment: why is this question tagged to swiftUI?

Comment: Under what class are you writing code?

Comment: I thought it might be related to swiftUI but I remove the tag if it's not the case

Comment: I use a FirebaseGoogleCredentialProvider class that you can find here: https://github.com/NelsonParrilla/GoogleSignin-bug So I init a firebaseGoogleCredentialProvider and call the present function when I want to log in

Comment: I edited the question and created the repo https://github.com/NelsonParrilla/GoogleSignin-bug in order to better explain how it's implemented